# What exactly are UV lenses?

Tags: optics

Edmund Optics has [these UV lenses](https://www.edmundoptics.co.uk/c/uv-lenses/784/#) listed on their site but I'm not quite sure what it means for a lens to be 'UV'. Do glass lenses have significant issues transferring UV (I would also appreciate the correct terminology for this behaviour) or is this simply about avoiding aberration?

Comment: The description at the bottom of the page says: _"UV Lenses are optical lenses consisting of a single or multiple elements that have been designed for optimal performance when used with ultraviolet light. Ultraviolet lenses utilize specific substrates, anti-reflection coatings, or a combination of the two to maintain performance when operating below 400nm."_

Comment: Yes but the notion of 'performance' here is fuzzy to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a lot of "regular" glasses absorb in the UV, meaning you can't use them as lenses without suffering losses. In addition, They probably have coatings to make them anti-reflective, making the loss due to reflection decrease as well (as absorption loss)